# How do I protect the data in Web SQL permanently, so that nobody can delete my data?

Tags: html, web-sql

I am storing some of my data on the client side (browser's Web SQL). Of course data is permanently stored, but if the intruder writes a program to clear the local storage (`localstorage.clear()`) this function will delete my entire data in Web SQL.

So how do I protect my data in Web SQL permanently?

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [HTML5 Doctor](http://html5doctor.com/introducing-web-sql-databases/):

> Please beware that as of 18th November the W3C is no longer actively working on the Web SQL Database specification.

Taken from the [W3C's spec page](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/):

[image: a]

On that basis, it wouldn't surprise me if there is a security hole that allows for the local storage to be wiped. Web SQL is deprecated - don't use it.

Comment: Ok..suppose i use indexed database..but again how do i protect the data from localstorage.clear()

Comment: I love I see this kind of answer all over the place when there is no real alternative to "SQL in the browser", IndexedDB is not ready yet in all the platforms. W3C's Spec is deprecated != Is not supported. Long Live WebSQL.

Answer (score 0):

`localstorage.clear()` is nothing to do with WebSQL or IndexedDB. These are three different API. All of them are temporary storage. They can be wipe out any time.

There is no such thing as "intruder". All codes run on your page are you wrote or trusted.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot protect your data on the client side.  However, WebSQL will not be affected by localStorage, this is a completely different storage mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

You can't protect data on the client side.
It doesn't matter what API you are using, you need to assume at all times that the data on the client side can be compromised or lost.